# Enter keypress 'ignored' using jquery autocomplete tagit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, tag-it

I'm using [Tagit!](http://webspirited.com/tagit/#demos) with jQuery autocomplete.

It works a treat, retrieving known search words from a database as long as the user clicks one of the returned words.

If, however, user <kbd>↓</kbd>s and hits <kbd>enter</kbd>, the tag is created but the value/Id from the selected item is not stored. In other words, the "select" method is ignored, and this is critical. I have attempted a slew of keypress detections, but none work.

```
var theTags = $('#Keywords');
theTags.tagit({
      allowSpaces: true, 
      autocomplete: {
          source: function (request, response) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: webroot + "handlers/ACKeyword.ashx",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {
                      q: request.term.replace($('#hdnFound').val().trim(), "").trim()
                  },
                  success: function (data) {
                      response($.map(data.what, function (item) {                               
                          return {
                              label: item.name,
                              id: item.id
                          }
                      }));
                  }
              });
          },
          select: function (event, ui) {                
              // Doesn't fire on enter?
              itemId = ui.item.id;
              theTags.tagit("createTag", ui.item.value);
              $('#hdnKey').val($('#hdnKey').val().trim() + "," + ui.item.id);
              return false;
          }

      }
  },
})
```

You can tell a bad coder by how angry they get when their code doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't with tag-it, but it may work fow what you need, have a new one trigger on spacebar: https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue .. @Rufyan : if this issue is resolved then let me know